# How to disable all Comments in Wordpress?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, comments, disable

I would like to disable all COMMENTS on my WordPress installation. From what I see I can disable only comments for new posts (in Setting), I can disable comments for posts (using Bulk Actions), but there is no bulk actions to disable comments for media files. I am not really interested in installing more plugins that could do it.

There should be one nice switch that would enable/disable all comments on WordPress. I am sure this can be done with SQL (either over shell or phpMyAdmin).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable comments for existing posts using Bulk Edit, but this is not possible for existing media files. You can do both with a single SQL command (please verify `wp_your_table_with_posts` value to match your installation):

```
UPDATE wp_your_table_with_posts SET comment_status = 'closed';
```

You can disable comments for all new posts either by hand as administrator unchecking Settings / Discussion / Allow people to submit comments on new posts, or using SQL command (again, please verify `wp_your_table_with_posts` value to match your installation):

```
UPDATE wp_your_table_with_options SET option_value = NULL WHERE option_name = 'default_comment_status';
```